# "ELF: not found" and "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" while installing Stata12 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: software-installation, 12.10

I'm trying to install Stata12 on Ubuntu 12.10.
I stored the directory stata12 64bit in `/usr/local` and then I followed this procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceview-3.0-common
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtksourceview-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so.0
sudo apt-get install libgnomeprint2.2-0
cd /usr/local/stata12/
sudo chmod -R 755 .
sudo sh setrwxp now
sudo ./stinit
```

After this line the terminal returns:

```
./stinit: 1: ./stinit: ELF: not found
./stinit: 1: ./stinit: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

(with some strange matrix of numbers before and after ELF)

Any idea on this phenomenon?

Answer (score 0):

Determine Drive Information

We assume that the hard drive is physically installed and detected by the BIOS.
To determine the path that your system has assigned to the new hard drive, open a terminal and run:
sudo lshw -C disk

Partitioning Using GParted
System > Administration > GNOME Partition Editor (or 'Partition Editor') is not available, install "GParted" using "sudo apt-get install gparted" from the command line, "Add/Remove Software" (or "Add/Remove...") from the Applications menu, or "Synaptic Package Manager" from the System > Administration menu. Open GParted and let's get started.

gksudo gparted

for more into follow this link:-
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks! I've installed ubuntu just few days ago and in these days my knowledge of computers is slowly improving. I don't ave any new hard drive, i'm just trying to install a programm for statistical analysis.Could you please write the lines to carry me to solve the problem with the installation? thank you very much anyhow!

Comment: I can manually find the file "stinit" in the directory, but I don't know how to run the (binary?) executable outside the terminal. :(

Comment: Anyway it produces a kind of a text file named "invalid encoding"